# R: Remove repeated pairs from input to vecotrized function before running function

Tags: r, list, vectorization, apply

I've written some code to find [amicable pairs](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Amicable_pairs). Currently, it is very inefficient and I'm trying to fix its problems. As part of this, I have a function `areAmicablePairs(a,b)` that does exactly what you'd expect it to do, except that it can't handle cases where `a` or `b` are 1.

To try and find every amicable pair for `a` and `b` under some number `n`, I've ran `which(outer(2:n,2:n,Vectorize(areAmicablePairs)),arr.ind = TRUE)`. It didn't take me long to notice a very obvious inefficiency in how inputs are fed to this function. Specifically, there's repetition. For example, it will check if 100 and 101 are amicable pairs and will later check if 101 and 100 are, an equivalent case.

This gives me my question, without storing a list in memory or making such a list and filtering it down at run time, both of which I assume are very inefficient (I really don't want to store, say, a 20,000 by 20,000 list in memory), how can I feed this vecotrized function the list of unique pairs of numbers from 2 to n?  I could make a very carefully-constructed for loop, but the existence of functions like `apply`, `mapply`, and `unique` has me hoping that there's a better way.

Example:
Suppose that I use this as a placeholder for `areAmicablePairs`:

```
areAmicablePairs<-function(a,b)
{
    return(a==b)
}
```

Then I am trying to run `which(outer(2:1000,2:1000,Vectorize(areAmicablePairs)),arr.ind = TRUE)` without repeating equivalent inputs such as `a=5, b=2` and `a=2, b=5`.

Comment: please, try to give a [mcve] so we can actually help

Comment: @denis How's this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `combinations()` from `gtools` to create such unique pairs (permutations with irrelevance of order). But that will still create a very large matrix of size:

[image: $\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$].

```
library(gtools)

n <- 20
r <- 2
result <- combinations(n, r)
```

Another option is to replicate that behaviour by simply incrementing the two variables in a more efficient way. Instead of running through all numbers of `2:n` for the first variable and `2:n` for the second, you could set `b <- a` after incrementing `a` and checking all `b:n`

Here's some pseudo code just to illustrate the incrementing

```
a <- 2
b <- 2

testing_numbers <- function(a, b, lim){
  while (a < lim){
    while (b < lim){
      if (some_condition){
        paste(a, b, True)
      } else{
        b <- b + 1
      }
    }
    a <- a + 1
    b <- a
  }
}
```

For your vectorised function that means you could use something like this:

```
while (a < lim){
  # vector of the numbers still to test
  b_vec <- a:lim
  # repeat vector of the first number in the pair
  a_rep <- rep(a, times=length(b_vec))
  # apply function to both of these vectors
  mapply(your_test, b_vec, a_rep)
  a <- a + 1
}
```

Comment: ```combinations``` isn't viable for large inputs. As its documentation warns, you'll quickly run in to C stack usage errors.

Answer (score 3):

If we need more efficiency, then an option is `comboGeneral` from `RcppAlgos`

```
library(RcppAlgos)
n <- 20
r <- 2
result2 <- comboGeneral(n, r)
```

-checking

```
identical(resul2, gtool::combinations(n, r))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: For `n=20,000`, as mentioned in the question, `RcppAlgos::comboGeneral()` does not complain about C stack size limits and just gets on with it, which is nice. As opposed to `gtools::combinations()`. But it still means that generating all these pairs at once will take up ~1.5 Gb of memory